# How to increase the clickable area in vuetify stepper component?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using stepper component and I want to increase the clickable area of  present inside the v-stepper-header

```
  <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-stepper>
        <v-stepper-header>
          <v-stepper-step
            editable
            step="1"
          >
            My clickable area ends here
          </v-stepper-step>
  
          <v-stepper-step
            editable
            step="2"
          >
            My clickable area ends here
          </v-stepper-step>
          <v-stepper-step
            step="3"
            editable
          >
            Comparatively smaller
          </v-stepper-step>
          <v-stepper-step
            step="4"
            editable
          >
            Summary
          </v-stepper-step>
        </v-stepper-header>
      </v-stepper>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[image]

Here is my codepen if it helps
https://codepen.io/justforvue/pen/dyvRGaG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not found any API that supports this.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-stepper/

However, it seems achievable with some CSS.

Add a class name to the stepper component

```html
  <v-stepper class="my-stepper">
```

Apply the CSS for the relevant breakpoint.

```css
@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .my-stepper .v-stepper__step {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

Demo
https://codepen.io/kunukn/pen/017aee3ea77b3db560a25aa7617c4a27?editors=1100